# Google Apps Script to count number of emails sent/received yesterday, that has a certain label, then save # daily to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I looked at the below question and it gets me half way there.  I can run Suyash Gandhi's code and it will count the total number of emails with a certain label for all of time.  I am trying to get a count for (A) # of emails sent and (B) # emails received by label for a specific date.

[Google Apps Script to count number of emails received yesterday, that has certain label, then save # daily to spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069253/google-apps-script-to-count-number-of-emails-received-yesterday-that-has-certai?newreg=e1ad732cde2e4c629ad59f391b207cc8)

For example,

```
Label    Date       #Received    #Sent
Test     1/1/2017   2            4
Test     1/2/2017   2            4
Test     1/3/2017   2            4
Test     1/4/2017   2            0 
Test     1/10/2017  2            8 

Vs what the code currently does:
Label    Date       Count
Test     1/10/2017   30
```

I'd like to run the script say at midnight to count the prior days emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with this script, hope it helps.

```
var labelName = "purgeMailTest";
var theDate ="2017-01-28";

function myFunction() 
{
  var dayOfMonth = theDate.split("-");
  var nextDayOfMonth = parseInt(dayOfMonth[2])+1;
  var nextDate = dayOfMonth[0]+"-"+dayOfMonth[1]+"-"+nextDayOfMonth;
  var sentCount = 0, receivedCount = 0;

  //Sent count
  var sentSearchQuery = "label:"+labelName+" before:"+nextDate+" after:"+theDate+" is:sent";
  var threads = GmailApp.search(sentSearchQuery, 0, 500);

  for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    sentCount = sentCount + threads[i].getMessages().length;
  }

  Logger.log(theDate +":"+sentCount+" sent");

  //Received count
  var receivedSearchQuery = "label:"+labelName+" before:"+nextDate+" after:"+theDate+" -is:sent";
  var threads = GmailApp.search(receivedSearchQuery, 0, 500);


  for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    receivedCount = receivedCount + threads[i].getMessageCount();
  }

  Logger.log(theDate +":"+receivedCount+" received");

}
```

To summarize:

I have simply used gmail search filters to get the sent and received emails for a particular date.

How to use this script?

change label name according to your environment and also set the **theDate** variable as the date you want and run the script. And when it finishes, check the logs.

Let me know if any help required further.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am new to google apps scripting and will make some attempts to adjust the code you provided to do what I need. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome! I'm guessing you might struggle with date format, use utilities.formatdate for that.