# Get number of unread mails for a date associated to a label with Gmail Api

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to archive a RESTfull service in Gmail Api that I can use to retrieve a number of unread mails for a date associated to a label, but I don't know if they have something like that or if I can do it, I investigated in [Gmail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/?hl=es-419)

Comment: Have you come across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069253/google-apps-script-to-count-number-of-emails-received-yesterday-that-has-certai)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can retrieve Unread mails for specific labels and date. You need to pass 2 additional fields with auth, userId and other fields.
`labelIds: "INBOX",
q: "after:2018/1/24, is:unread"`

`lableIds` can take array of lables, so you can specify all the labels you need.
`q` field is for query.
Visit this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) to know various queries you can make for `q` field.